# Pass string from Android App to Wear Os App

Tags: android, wear-os

I am an Android Developer. I need to develop an Wear Os app that can display the text from android app that i build. May i ask any Example because i cannot found any of the Bluetooth communication example on this and is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To sync data between a phone and a Wear OS watch, you don't use Bluetooth directly. The simplest way to do this is with Wear's Data API; step-by-step documentation is here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/accessing (and there's a link to an example on that page).

Comment: Cause now i plan to do a project that What Raspberry Pi display with auto sync to A Smart Watch. But i saw many other people say that Raspberry Pi cannot direct connect with Watch need to use a phone as middle man. You got any recommend on how the architecture can be?

Comment: Changing the question (sending from Raspberry Pi rather than an Android phone) doesn't really change the answer; the Data API is still the supported method to send data to the watch. And to do this from a non-Android device of any nature, you'd need to go via the linked phone.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to send data via a direct Bluetooth connection, but it's not specifically supported by Wear OS. So it'd be the same as making & using a BT connection to any Android device; there's nothing Wear-specific about it.